# Mysql query match id in field

Tags: php, mysql

i am adding multiple category id in field like ,   127-157-526-5222-

now i am trying to fetch data but getting nothing. can anyone help me in this problem, getting 0 result.

my query is

```
SELECT * FROM tblprods WHERE FIND_IN_SET('157', tblprods.categories)
```

Comment: FIND_IN_SET works for CSV

Comment: 127-157-526-5222 is one id or four id?

Comment: `i am adding multiple category id in field` This is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since `FIND_IN_SET` works for comma separated values (CSV) try replacing the hyphens with comma first.

```
SELECT * FROM tblprods WHERE FIND_IN_SET('157', REPLACE(tblprods.categories,'-',','));
```

**Caution:**

[**Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

#### YES